# Snakemake limit the memory usage of jobs

Tags: memory, snakemake

I need to run 20 genomes with a snakemake. So I am using basic steps like alignment, markduplicates, realignment, basecall recalibration and so on in snakemake. The machine I am using has up to 40 virtual cores and 70G memory and I run the program like this.

```
snakemake -s Snakefile -j 40
```

This works fine, but as soon as It runs markduplicates along other programs, it stops as I think it overloads the 70 available giga and crashes.
Is there a way to set in snakemake the memory limit to 60G in total for all programs running? I would like snakemake runs less jobs in order to stay under 60giga, is some of the steps require a lot of memory. The command line below crashed as well and used more memorya than allocated.

```
snakemake -s Snakefile -j 40 --resources mem_mb=60000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to specify `--resources mem_mb=60000` on the command line, you need also to specify `mem_mb` for the rules you want to keep in check. E.g.:

```
rule markdups:
    input: ...
    ouptut: ...
    resources:
        mem_mb= 20000
    shell: ...

rule sort:
    input: ...
    ouptut: ...
    resources:
        mem_mb= 1000
    shell: ...
```

This will submit jobs in such way that you don't exceed a total of 60GB at any one time. E.g. this will keep running at most 3 `markdups` jobs, or 2 markdups jobs and 20 `sort` jobs, or 60 `sort` jobs.

Rules without `mem_mb` will not be counted towards memory usage, which is probably ok for rules that e.g. copy files and do not need much memory.

How much to assign to each rule is mostly up to your guess. `top` and [htop](https://htop.dev/) commands help in monitoring jobs and figuring out how much memory they need. More elaborated solutions could be devised but I'm not sure it's worth it... If you use a job scheduler like slurm, the log files should give you the peak memory usage of each job so you can use them for future guidance. Maybe others have better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot..What if I have 10 rules? Do I have to include mem_mb is all rules, also how can I calculate how much to put in each rule? Sorry this is just a little bit confusing for me at this stage.

Comment: @user3224522 No worries - I edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: thanks! if for bwa mem I have threads=3 and mem_mb=30000, will this mean 30000*3? or for all jobs independently from threads it will not exceed 30G?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `thread=3` argument won't be taken into account for computing memory usage... Just experiment with it and see...